# Bad request. HTTP POST to api

Tags: javascript, json, express, google-api, request

I'm trying to return some data from an api, however when I hit the server I receive a bad request message. I think the issue lies with my JSON Stringify, have I used this function correctly to concatenate my request body?

Output:

```
{ request: 
   { passengers: { kind: 'qpxexpress#passengerCounts', adultCount: 1 },
     slice: [ [Object] ],
     saleCountry: 'GB',
     ticketingCountry: 'GB',
     solutions: 10 } }
Upload successful!  Server responded with: {
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "badRequest",
    "message": "Invalid inputs: received empty request."
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Invalid inputs: received empty request."
 }
}
```

Code:

```
var express = require('express')
var router = express.Router()
var request = require('request')

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' })
})

let flightRequest = {
  "request": {
      "passengers": {
        "kind": "qpxexpress#passengerCounts",
        "adultCount": 1
      },
      "slice": [{
        "kind": "qpxexpress#sliceInput",
        "origin": "LHR",
        "destination": "OSL",
        "date": "2016-12-03",
        "permittedDepartureTime": {
          "kind": "qpxexpress#timeOfDayRange",
          "earliestTime": "06:00",
          "latestTime": "11:00"
        }}],
      "saleCountry": "GB",
      "ticketingCountry": "GB",
      "solutions": 10
    }
  }

console.log(JSON.stringify("hello" + flightRequest))

JSON.stringify(flightRequest)
console.log(flightRequest)

request.post({url:'https://www.googleapis.com/qpxExpress/v1/trips/search?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX', flightRequest: flightRequest}, function optionalCallback(err, httpResponse, body) {
  if (err) {
    return console.error('upload failed:', err);
  }
  console.log('Upload successful!  Server responded with:', body);
});

module.exports = router
```

Comment: `I think the issue lies with my JSON Stringify` - while you've used the function JSON.stringify, you've never used the result of the function, so therefore that's not the problem ... unless the flightRequest parameter to that API needs to be a JSON string, in that case you need to supply that parameter a JSON string, not a javascript object

Comment: Having a brief look at the API, I think you need to, at least do the following ... change `flightRequest: flightRequest` to `flightRequest: JSON.stringify(flightRequest)`

Comment: I've followed the documentation to build out the request body, the bit I'm getting caught on is passing that to the URL string. I tried the above with no luck unfortunately.

Comment: so if you pass in `flightRequest: JSON.stringify(flightRequest)` do you get the same error?

Comment: Yes that sends the same error

Comment: I don't think you can add flightrequest to "hello" because flightrequest is a JSON object and "hello" is a string

Comment: Oh, I see, `request.post` has no idea what the `flightRequest` property is, it wont send that

Comment: Have you tried console.log("hello" + JSON.stringify(flightrequest))

Comment: @hmedia1, yep that returns:
`"hello[object Object]"`. However, I have stripped this back, please see updated code above.

Comment: Can you post an ideal output ?   Are you trying to add a k:v pair to the JSON object ?

Comment: When i run `"console.log(JSON.stringify('hello' + flightrequest));"` I also get 
"hello[object Object]"

Comment: but when i run `"console.log('hello' + JSON.stringify(flightrequest));"` I get:
hello{"request":{"passengers":{"kind":"qpxexpress#passenge...  etc..

Comment: This is why I'm asking, because simply appending the string wouldn't produce valid JSON, but I don't know what you're trying to achieve

Comment: Expected response. I am trying to build a query string to post to a third party API that will return a list of results back. https://developers.google.com/qpx-express/v1/trips/search#response

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to post the request as follows

```
request({
    url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/qpxExpress/v1/trips/search?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    method: "POST",
    json: JSON.stringify(flightRequest)
}, function optionalCallback(err, httpResponse, body) { ...
```

or it could be

```
request.post({
    url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/qpxExpress/v1/trips/search?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    json: JSON.stringify(flightRequest)
}, ...
```

Answer (score 0):

> have I used this function correctly to concatenate my request body?

**This Code**

- ```
  let flightRequest = 
  {
    "request": {
      "passengers": {
        "kind": "qpxexpress#passengerCounts",
        "adultCount": 1
      },
      "slice": [
        {
          "kind": "qpxexpress#sliceInput",
          "origin": "LHR",
          "destination": "OSL",
          "date": "2016-12-03",
          "permittedDepartureTime": {
            "kind": "qpxexpress#timeOfDayRange",
            "earliestTime": "06:00",
            "latestTime": "11:00"
          }
        }
      ],
      "saleCountry": "GB",
      "ticketingCountry": "GB",
      "solutions": 10
    }
  }
  let flightAppend = {"appended text":"hello"}
  var obj = Object.assign(flightAppend, flightRequest)
  console.log(JSON.stringify(obj))
  ```

**Produces This Output**

- ```
  {
    "appended text": "hello",
    "request": {
      "passengers": {
        "kind": "qpxexpress#passengerCounts",
        "adultCount": 1
      },
      "slice": [
        {
          "kind": "qpxexpress#sliceInput",
          "origin": "LHR",
          "destination": "OSL",
          "date": "2016-12-03",
          "permittedDepartureTime": {
            "kind": "qpxexpress#timeOfDayRange",
            "earliestTime": "06:00",
            "latestTime": "11:00"
          }
        }
      ],
      "saleCountry": "GB",
      "ticketingCountry": "GB",
      "solutions": 10
    }
  }
  ```

I don't know if that's what you're looking for, or which side of the API you're on, but the output is valid JSON

As opposed to the original code which produces "hello[object Object]"